# Is there a more efficient way I should be writing a query with multiple joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I wrote like the below one however multiple of the Views I'm using in the query have > 50 million rows. The query is super slow (2.5 minutes) even despite only selecting top 50 rows.

Is there a different way I should be writing a query like this to speed up the execution time other than using indexes?

```
SELECT TOP 50
       ECO.ITEMNUMBER,
       ECO.PRODUCTNAME,
       SUM(POH.SCHEDULEDQUANTITY) AS WIPQTY,
       SUM(ITV.QTY) AS SOLDQTY,
       SUM(IOH.QTY) AS ONHANDQTY,
       SUM(SOC.ORIGINALORDERQTY) AS ONORDERQTY
FROM ECO
     LEFT JOIN ITV ON ECO.ITEMNUMBER = ITV.ITEMID
     LEFT JOIN IOH ON ECO.ITEMNUMBER = IOH.ITEMID
     LEFT JOIN SOC ON ECO.ITEMNUMBER = SOC.PRODUCTNUMBER
     LEFT JOIN POH ON ECO.ITEMNUMBER = POH.ITEMNUMBER
WHERE ECO.PRODUCTGROUPID = '1'
  AND ITV.REFERENCECATEGORY = 'REF0'
  AND ITV.INVENTLOCATIONID = 'MAIN'
  AND ITV.DATECLOSED > GETDATE() - 365
GROUP BY ECO.ITEMNUMBER,
         ECO.PRODUCTNAME;
```

Comment: FYI, it's generally frowned upon to treat dates like numbers; numbers are *not* dates. If you want to subtract 365 days from a date, then use `DATEADD` (note as well that 365 days <> 1 year, if that is your intent too).

Comment: You don't have an ORDER BY clause at the end of your query, so how do you know which 50 rows you are getting?

Comment: Is your `sum()` with `group by` returning more than 50 rows? How many rows does your query return? Because maybe your `top` statement doesn't really matter.

Comment: This also looks like it could give the wrong results. Say you have two ITV records that match an ECO record for those join conditions. Then say you also have 3 IOH records that match the join condition. The `SUM()` on that column will be **SIX**, not three, because the query would first find the 2 matching ITV records, and for each of them do the join to find the 3 matching IOH records. Now add SOC and POH, and those multiplications happen again.

Comment: *`WHERE ECO.PRODUCTGROUPID = '1'`* Is it an `int` or `string`?

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` to `ITV` is an implicit `INNER JOIN` by the way, due the requirement that the columns `REFERENCECATEGORY`, `INVENTLOCATIONID` and `DATECLOSED` all have a non-`NULL` value; a column *cannot* have a non-`NULL` value if the row wasn't found. Is this intended? If not, then the clauses should be moved to the `ON`. If it is, then the `JOIN` should be changed to an `INNER JOIN` to avoid misleading others who read the SQL.

Comment: _... however multiple of the Views I'm using in the query_ You will need to consider / tune the queries used by the views as well. Ultimately performance issues are diagnosed by looking at the execution plan - not guessing.

Comment: If this query is joining to other *views* then it's impossible to make any meaningful suggestions without also seeing the view queries; it's impossible to make any meaningful index recommendations without knowing the cardinality / selectivity of the data. If you're selecting top 50 random rows then you're computing aggregations you don't use so it would make more sense to filter rows first before aggregating.

Comment: This question is not answerable without knowing the tables and indexes involved, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 0):

You said "multiple of the Views I'm using in the query have > 50 million rows".  So you are querying Views and not tables? If so, you might want to look at the performance of those views first.

Also, maybe there is a normalization issue if you are trying to join one 50 million row view to another.  There might be a better strategy.

Even good indexing and good query writing will struggle when joining 50 million rows against 50 million other rows.  Maybe you can summarize the data before this query.  Perhaps in a temporary table.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have indexes on the columns you are filtering and/or joining on.

If performance is still slow after adding indexes, try creating a lookup table and update the lookup table every time you do an CRUD action on one of those tables. (Or sync them every hour or so).

Comment: Just to be clear the indexes needed to make this as fast as possible are (ECO.ITEMNUMBER,  ECO.PRODUCTNAME), ITV.ITEMID, IOH.ITEMID, SOC.PRODUCTNUMBER, POH.ITEMNUMBER.   You don't need to make a new index if this is already the primary key for the table.

Comment: The ITV index should be more complicated: `(ITV.ReferenceCategory, ITV.InventLocationID, ITV.ItemID, ITV.DateClosed, ITV.QTY)`.